# How to create a common desktop icon only if setupper is running elevated with admin rights

Tags: inno-setup

```
[ICONS]    
Name: {commondesktop}\{#oemtitle}; Filename: {app}\app.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; IconIndex: 0; Flags: createonlyiffileexists
```

How to make the above icon only if running elevated,  currently my setupper displays an error dialog for this icon when setupper is executed with the lower permissions as I have PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed=dialog that allows end-user to choose to install to themself only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`{autodesktop}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=autodesktop) to create the icon on common desktop when elevated and on user's desktop otherwise.

```
[Icons]    
Name: {autodesktop}\{#oemtitle}; Filename: {app}\app.exe; ...
```

---

To answer your literal question: To create an icon when running elevated only, use [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) with [`IsAdminInstallMode` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode) (or [`IsAdmin`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmin)).

```
[Icons]    
Name: {commondesktop}\{#oemtitle}; Filename: {app}\app.exe; \
    WorkingDir: {app}; IconIndex: 0; Flags: createonlyiffileexists; \
    Check: IsAdminInstallMode
```